# Как передать cookies/headers в библиотеку python webbrowser?

Tags: python, webbrowser

Мне необходимо открыть закрытую страницу в браузере с помощью python после некоторых действий пользователя. Это не должна быть эмуляция типа Селениума, так как мне нужно открыть браузер именно на компьютере пользователя. Но и при этом нужно передать кукисы/хедерсы, чтобы сайт понял, что пришел старый пользователь и его нужно впустить на эту закрытую страницу. Как это сделать, можете подсказать? Перепробовал кучу вариантов - пока ничего не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Модуль [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) рассчитан только на открытие браузера и остановки работы программы, пока браузер открыт. Если прям совсем необходимо передавать куки в браузер через этот модуль, то нужно придумывать костыль *(через модуль os скорее всего)* нахождения нужной директории профиля браузера и через модуль **sqlite3** вписать нужные куки в файл *cookies.sqlite*

Например, по этой директории в windows системе можно найти профиль браузера Firefox и добавить строки cookies в БД.

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%случайные символы%\cookies.sqlite
```

Comment: Может знаете какой-то другой способ решить задачу? Может без webbrowser?

Comment: С открытием браузера не смогу подсказать как проще всего поступить, только приходит на ум сделать все через обычные запросы или тот же селениум. Других движков кроме селениума для управления браузером не знаю (макросы и автокликеры вряд ли подойдут). Или делать костыли принудительной записью в файл cookies.sqlite

Comment: Спасибо за идею в любом случае. Не знал о ней.

Comment: В модуле requests просто добавлять и изменять cookies/headers. Я не знаю что у вас за проект, поэтому как то так

Comment: Это я понимаю. Просто мне нужно именно открыть страницу в браузере пользователя, чтобы он ею дальше пользовался. Ну и не просто открыть страницу, а открыть именно закрытую часть сайта (то есть как-то передать туда кукисы или хедерсы)

Comment: Тогда надо копать ответ в сторону GUI интерфейсов (Qt5, Electron), возможно там получится найти ответ на вопрос